# Как в Vim настроить индентацию кода на Pascal/Deplhi/Oberon с BEGIN/END заглавными буквами?

Tags: pascal, vim, форматирование

Есть *Vim 8*.  И есть код (примерный) на паскалеподобном языке:

```pascal
BEGIN
i := 0;
IF i = 0 THEN
BEGIN
i := 1;
END;
END.
```

Выделяю его и жму `=`, чтобы отформатировать, но ничего не
происходит. При этом, если ключевые слова писать строчными, всё
работает. Как сказать *Vim*, чтобы он не обращал внимание на
регистр при индентации?

Comment: Логичный вопрос: что мешает использовать строчные буквы, если самому языку безразличен регистр? 
Лично мне бы было лень жмякать капслок или зажимать шифт для набора.

Comment: это может быть и Оберон - там заглавные обязательно

Comment: @Adokenai  Во-первых, как уже упомянул коллега, регистр безразличен не всем языкам.  Во-вторых, есть стилевые правила общих проектов и собственные предпочтения в личных.

Comment: А тип файла какой? Попробуйте вручную установить `:set filetype=Ada` например.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin Это работает лучше, но всё равно местами делает неверные отступы в коде на паскале.

Comment: Стало быть, в принципе оно работает. Тогда можно поставить тип файла `:set filetype=pascal`. А если особенности не устраивают, то поправить их в файле `$Vim\vim74\indent\pascal.vim`